# Reading a .txt file and appending each word into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm kind of on a time crunch, but this was one of my problems in my homework assignment. I am stuck, and I don't know what to do or how to proceed.

Our assignment was to open various text files and within each of the text files, we are supposed to add each word into a dictionary in which the key is the document number it came from, and the value is the word.

For example, one text file would be:

```
1
Hello, how are you?

I am fine and you?
```

Each of the text files begin with a number corresponding to it's title (for example, "document1.txt" begins with "1", "document2.txt" begins with "2", etc)

My teacher gave us this coding to help with stripping the punctuation and the lines, but I am having a hard time figuring out where to implement it.

```
data = re.split("[ .,:;!?\s\b]+|[\r\n]+", line)
data = filter(None, data)
```

I don't really understand where the filter(None, data) stuff comes into play, because all it does is return a code line of what it represents in memory.

Here's my code so far:

```
def invertFile(list_of_file_names):
    import re
    diction = {}
    emplist = []
    fordiction = []
    for x in list_of_file_names:
        afile = open(x, 'r')
        with afile as f:
            for line in f:
                savedSort = filterText(f)

def filterText(line):
    import re
    word_delimiters = [' ', ',', ';', ':', '.','?','!']
    data = re.split("[ .,:;!?\s\b]+|[\r\n]+", f)
    key, value = data[0], data[1:]
    diction[key] = value
```

How do I make it so each word is appended into a dictionary, where the key is the document it comes from, and the value are the words in the document? Thank you.

Comment: `filter` should be called right after `re.split`. You can do `list(data)` to convert the filter object to a list so you can print its contents. `filter` returns an iterable in Python 3, so that's what you're seeing

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I converted the filter into a list, but I am still getting an error with the return. I noticed while putting a print statement in, it doesn't convert everything in the document as list and it's still creating line breaks.